# Brand Assets not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, assets, launchimage

My image assets catalogue not working.I don't know what happen here also Launch screen is empty see my screen shots[image]

It strange launch screen is empty so why it showing me as splash screen. help me please[image]

[image]

Comment: In your `info.plist` file, is there an entry `UILaunchStoryboardName` ("Launch screen interface file base name")?

Comment: please don't add image directly.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have "LaunchScreen.storyboard" file in project folder. If it's there it will show in dropdown.

When you are showing image on "LaunchScreen.storyboard", you need to drag and drop images in resource folder.

App will not pick image from "Assets.xcassets".

Answer (score 0):

Click on you project, in the Info tab you have the line "Launch screen interface file base name"

You can just remove that line and delete LaunchScreen.storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If your ios version is 8 or grater then you have to use launchsreen.storyboard. So, set launch screen file as LaunchScreen and and set your image on that storyboard.

If you want to give support of ios 7 then you should use both Launch image source and Launch screen file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove reference to it from project settings. 
 notice your xcasstes folders , mine created **Images.xcassets** in addition to the **Assets.xcassets**.
i ended up deleting the Images.xcasstes to fix build errors